# Implicitly deciding which dictionary should be used

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python to analyze a large set of CSV data.  This data contains 4 different types of metrics for a given timestamp and host pair, with the metric type indicated in the first field of each row.  Here's a simplified example:

```
metric,timestamp,hostname,value
metric1,1488063747,example01.net,12
metric2,1488063747,example01.net,23
metric3,1488063747,example01.net,34
metric4,1488063747,example01.net,45
metric1,1488063788,example02.net,56
metric2,1488063788,example02.net,67
metric3,1488063788,example02.net,78
metric4,1488063788,example02.net,89
```

So, for every `row` (actually, a list within a list of lists) I make an index composed of the timestamp and hostname:

```
idx = row[1] + ',' + row[2]
```

Now, based on the contents of the first field (list element), I do something like:

```
if row[0] == 'metric1': metric_dict[idx] = row[3]
```

I do that for each of the 4 metrics.  It works, but it seems like there should be a better way.  It seems like I need to somehow implicitly or indirectly choose the dictionary to be used based on the contents of row[0], but my searches have not yielded a result.  In this case, 4 `if` lines are not tough, but it wouldn't be unusual for more metric types to be contained in a file.  Is it possible to do this and be left with however many dictionaries are needed after the list of lists is read?  Thank you.

Comment: You could nest those dicts in *another* dict, say `metrics`, where the keys are `"metric1"`, and the values are the appropriate dict, so, `metric[row[0]][idx]` is what you would end up using.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: not enough dicts.

Solution:

```
conversion_dict = {'metric1': metric1_dict, 'metric2': metric2_dict}

for row:
    conversion_dict[row[0]][idx] = row[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like

```
output = {}
for row in rows:
    # assuming this data is already split

    if not row[0] in output:
        output[row[0]] = {}
    idx = row[1] + ',' + row[2]
    output[row[0]][idx] = row[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a lot of table manipulation, you may find the `pandas` library helpful. If I understand correctly what you're trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

s = StringIO("""metric,timestamp,hostname,value
metric1,1488063747,example01.net,12
metric2,1488063747,example01.net,23
metric3,1488063747,example01.net,34
metric4,1488063747,example01.net,45
metric1,1488063788,example02.net,56
metric2,1488063788,example02.net,67
metric3,1488063788,example02.net,78
metric4,1488063788,example02.net,89
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s)
df.pivot(index="timestamp", columns='metric',values='value')
```

This yields:

```
metric      metric1  metric2  metric3  metric4
timestamp                                     
1488063747       12       23       34       45
1488063788       56       67       78       89
```